# List splitting in undesired way

Tags: python, list, built-in

> I am trying to create a list of selected functions from a given python module.
>   Here is an example script I have tried along with the outputs:

```
import os

def getfuncts(modyule):
    return (dir(modyule))

def pull_function(modyule):
    highgrade = []
    l = getfuncts(modyule)
    for func in l:

        if func[0].isalnum() and func[0].islower():
            highgrade += func

    print (l)
    print (highgrade)


pull_function(os)

l = ['EX_CANTCREAT', 'EX_CONFIG', 'EX_DATAERR', 'EX_IOERR', 'EX_NOHOST', …]
highgrade = ['a', 'b', 'o', 'r', 't', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 's', 's',…]
```

Q1. Why is the highgrade ouput list split into single characters like this?

Q2. How can I get a list of function names, (i.e. [abort, access, …])?

Comment: A1: Because you append single chars to `highgrade`. A2: From what?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a single character at a time to the `highgrade` list in the following line:

```
`highgrade += func`
```

Pretty sure you can accomplish what you want in one line:

```
print([l for l in dir(os) if l[0].isalnum() and l[0].islower()])
```

Gives:

```
['abc', 'abort', 'access', 'altsep', 'chdir', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`highgrade += func` means `highgrade.extend(func)`, and expects `func` to be an iterable. Here, `func` is a string, so extend iterates over its characters and appends each one to the `highgrade` list.

What you want is:

```
highgrade.append(func)
```

to append each string.